# Controlling Player Movement After Per Pixel Collision

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, xna-4.0

[image]

I have implemented a full per pixel collision system that accounts for rotation, and its very accurate. It returns a simple bool on collision.

However I am not sure how to handle the collision from the player movement point of view.

E.g. In the picture above, if the player is holding up on the left stick, he should be stopped, but if he is holding up + right diagonal on the left stick, he should slide northeast alongside the side of the red square almost naturally.

How do I go about this, to make the player’s momentum stop, but still give control for the player to move in direction not blocked by a collision.

I could do this kind of thing with simple untransformed rectangles, but going into per-pixel texture collision has made my brain explode today so I’m hoping you guys can help. Any advice would be massively appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit beyond me, but the keywords to search for are collision response. Also, note that there's a [game development site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) here too.

Comment: Thank you so much, i do some searching on collision response on per pixel now.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. For that you need to implement physics engine with your pixel based collision if you are willing to give natural effect in your game.

For that either you write your own game engine or use engine that is already there. For 2D game I highly recommended [Farseer Physics Engine](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/). It is out there for a long time. Now in stable condition and it surely wonderful.

It is developed using XNA only from scratch, and also performance wise it is far good.

Have a look at this. I hope I was able to give you answer. Please let me know if more details needed.